# What needs to be changed in the structure of the human body in order not to get poisoned with raw Fugu fish?

Tags: science-based, creature-design, biochemistry

The most poisonous fish in the world is the so-called puffer.  Its liver and other parts of the body contain a substance called tetrodotoxin, which is capable of paralyzing the respiratory muscles of any living creature and leading to its death.

Tetrodotoxin is the poison of puffer fish.  A neurotoxin that blocks electrical impulses in nerves by disrupting the flow of sodium ions into nerve cells.  Tetrodotoxin is approximately 500 to 1,000 times more potent than potassium cyanide.  One gram of fugu poison is enough to kill 500 people, and there is no known antidote.

Due to the last fact, I thought about the question: what needs to be changed (added / improved) the human digestive system, or more precisely the gastrointestinal tract, in order to be able to safely eat raw (not processed) Fugu fish and at the same time not die from  poisoning?

Note: Given the comments below my past questions, I want to mention that as an answer I need a biologically valid model to somehow allow my genetically modified humans to eat raw (unprocessed) Fugu fish safely for their health.

Comment: I am bit losing the point of all your questions playing around different permutations of specific armful substances. By now it should be clear what the generic trend should be.

Comment: At the moment, I am separately dealing with the resistance to common poisons of my genetically modified super soldiers (I am writing a book about their anotomy)

Comment: I have to side with @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica here, we have now seen half a dozen of these questions, and the answer to all of them was essentially "it's impossible".

Comment: Hello French. Not only do I side with @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica in this matter, but I'm inclined to flag further questions for deletion. [worldbuilding.se] is not meant to be your personal, free research team. We've shown you a number of times how to solve this problem. Please go forth with your newfound skills and be productive. (Or, better yet, start really participating in the community. As of posting this comment, you've asked 20 questions but offered only 2 answers.)

Answer (score 5):

## At first blush nothing needs to be done because Fugu-meat isn't poisonous *by itself*

Note that Fugu by itself **isn't poisonous**. As everybody that has seen a [map of fugu restaurants in Japan](https://www.google.com/maps/search/fugu+restaurants+in+japan/@35.1767265,135.3818044,7z/data=!3m1!4b1) can see: there are ways to extract that meat safely and serve it raw in the shape of Sashimi. For the unknowing: [Sashimi is slices of raw fish](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sashimi). The meat of the blowfish is perfectly safe for consumption *if extracted correctly*. There is no *treatment* or *processing* done to fugu sashimi that extends to more than careful cutting by a skilled chef, discarding all the inner organs and skin.

### Where does the toxin come from?

What is **not** safe for consumption are the organs that accumulate Tetrodotoxin (TTX) **from the bacteria that live in the fish** - those are [eyes, liver, ovaries, and skin.](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3867830) Repeat: Pufferfishes **don't** create the poison they are known for themselves. The toxin biosynthesis of the bacteria in the fish [has been explored](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F1934578X1501000501), the [bacteria have been identified](https://books.google.com/books?isbn=038725496X) and as a result, there have been attempts to remove the toxin by selective feeding of fish.

### Why doesn't fugu poison itself?

The toxin acts on the neurons by inhibiting the sodium channels, and the pufferfish itself is supposedly insensitive to TTX by having a different structure of these channels, [as this paper stipulates](https://www.cell.com/current-biology/comments/S0960-9822(05)01368-0):

> Thus, the sodium channel Na<sub>v</sub>1.4a in both fugu and *Tetraodon* is likely to be resistant to TTX and responsible for rendering the pufferfish muscle fibers insensitive to TTX.

## Fugu can exist without the Bacteria

Also, there have been Fugu farms that breed pufferfish in an environment that utterly lacks the TTX-producing bacteria. [These fugu from Usuki](https://www.nytimes.com/2008/05/04/world/asia/04fugu.html) have been found to be totally non-poisonous.

## If you must...

Technically it *could* be possible to splice the gene that gives pufferfish its different sodium channel structure into humans to replace the standard sodium channel gene, but such is **not possible with nowadays technology**. The best we can do at the moment is [do so on octopus tissue](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/1660007/). The resulting neurons seem to work almost the same, so nothing else would be needed to be different but the structure of one protein group. A side effect might be additional insensitivity to [saxitoxin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saxitoxin), which also attacks the sodium channels.

Currently, it is not known if Pufferfish-like neurons have the same or a different signal transmission speed as mammal neurons, so further side effects can not be determined.

Comment: @FrenchThompson3, it's the second time you order a poster to delete their answer. That's not how we treat users here. If there are points you disagree with, just leave a comment, and if you think an answer doesn't answer a question flag it as not an answer or low quality, but then it will be the community to decide, not you.

Answer (score 4):

There are animals which have developed insensitivity to tetrodotoxin (TTX).

One of them is the [garter snake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_garter_snake)

> The common garter snake uses toxicity for both offense and defense. On the offensive side, the snake's venom can be toxic to some of its smaller prey, such as mice and other rodents. On the defensive side, the snake uses its resistance to toxicity to provide an important antipredator capability. A study on the evolutionary development of resistance of tetrodotoxin tested between two populations of Thamnophis and then tested inside a population of T. sirtalis. Those that were exposed to and lived in the same environment as the newts (Taricha granulosa) that produce tetrodotoxin when eaten were more immune to the toxin

This [paper](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/2447944/) seems to correlate insensitivity to TTX to a modified conformation of the proteins involved in the binding with TTX, resulting in a quicker release of the bound toxin

> suggesting that the lower association rate of toxin binding to toxin-insensitive subtypes is not due to decreased surface charge but rather to a slower protein conformational step. The increased rates of toxin dissociation from insensitive subtypes can be attributed to the loss of a few specific bonding interactions in the binding site such as loss of a hydrogen bond with the N-1 hydroxyl group

This is however no modification of the digestive system, rather a modification of the whole nervous system in the way proteins are coded.